# Can't figure out why this doesn't give me any output value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm extremely new to JavaScript and programming in general. Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
function computeLoan(){
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
    var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
    var months = document.getElementById('months').value;
    var interest = (amount * (interest_rate * .01)) / months;
    var payment = ((amount / months) + interest).toFixed(2);
    payment = payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "Monthly Payment = $"+payment;
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Loan Amount: $<input id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="1000000"                 onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
<p>Interest Rate: <input id="interest_rate" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10" step=".1" onchange="computeLoan()">%</p>
<p>Months: <input id="months" type="number" min="1" max="72" value="1"                  step="1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p
<h2 id="payment"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Any errors in your browsers web inspectors console?

Comment: as soon as you fix the typo: `</p` should be `</p>`, your code will work http://jsfiddle.net/ya1n7vym/

Comment: Nevermind guys. Sorry. Was as simple as an unclosed </p> tag at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Months - you're missing a bracket on your closing `<p>` tag.  This is causing your `<h2>` to be undefined

```
<p>Months: <input id="months" type="number" min="1" max="72" value="1" step="1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p
```

the

```
</p
```

at the end is your problem.